# Rename query string parameter if it exists

Tags: java, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to use [Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html#install) to rename a query string parameter if it exists.  I want to rename "foo" to "bar".

Examples:

- `/hello/hey/?foo=123` should be `/hello/hey/?bar=123`
- `/nascar/?a=b&foo=lol` should be `/nascar/?a=b&bar=lol`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<urlrewrite>

    <rule>
       <from>^(.*)(\?|&)foo=(.*)$</from>
       <to type="redirect">$1$2bar=$3</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```